# How can I run Hive Explain command from java code?

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I want to run Hive and Impala Explain and compute stats command from java code. So that I can use the collected information for my analysis purpose. If any one have any idea please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it as any other jdbc query against impala.

The compute stats query for a table called temp would be "compute stats temp" and you can pass this as an argument for the jdbc statement.execute

Similarly, to explain a query, say "select count( * ) from temp" the query to pass as an argument for statement.execute is "explain select count(*) from temp".

Comment: I am glad it helped. Can you accept the answer in that case.